# Tab Vs Space preferences in Vim

Tags: vim, whitespace, preferences

Vim is very accommodating when it comes to tab Vs. space preferences. As I understand it, the `tabstop` setting indicates the width of a tab character. The `shiftwidth` setting specifies how many columns to increment/decrement when using the <kbd><<</kbd> and <kbd>>></kbd> commands, whereas the `softtabstop` setting influences the amount of whitespace to be inserted when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in insert mode. If `expandtab` is on, the tab key inserts `softtabstop` number of space characters. Whereas with `expandtab` switched off, pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key inserts a the smallest possible number of tab+space characters that matches `softtabstop`. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

This final point makes me wonder: is there a practical case where you wouldn't want `shiftwidth == tabstop && tabstop == softtabstop`? I can't think of one. As far as I am concerned, it would be most convenient if I could set all 3 of these to the same value, in one single assignment. e.g. calling:

```
:set stab=4
```

which would be equivalent to running:

```
:set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be done?

---

### *UPDATE*

**Thanks for the replies so far from *too much php*, *hobbs* and *kaiser.se*. Rather than reply to each individually, I'm updating the question here.**

### Softtabstop with expandtab switched off

I said above that with expandtab switched off, pressing the Tab key inserts a the smallest possible number of tab+space characters that matches `softtabstop`. I stand by that, but I think I need to explain what I meant. I shall attempt to do so by way of a few examples. To follow along, run `:set list` so that you can see tab characters.

`tabstop=4 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab`

In insert mode, pressing the tab key inserts 2 space characters. Press the tab key a second time, and instead of inserting two more space characters (for a total of 4 space characters) it replaces the previous 2 spaces with a single tab character. Tabstop is set to 4, so a single tab character has the same width as 4 spaces.

`tabstop=4 softtabstop=6 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab`

In insert mode, pressing the tab key inserts 1 tab character plus 2 spaces. The tab character has a width of 4, so the total width is 6, and this is achieved using 3 characters. Pressing the tab key a second time inserts two tab characters, and removes the two spaces that were inserted previously. The total width is 12, and this is achieved using 3 characters.

In both of these examples, Vim inserts the minimum possible number of tab+space characters that matches softtabstop.

If I am working with expandtab switched off, I can't see myself wanting the extra granular control that can be achieved by setting softtabstop to a different value from tabstop. It would still be useful for me to be able to set `tabstop`, `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` to the same value with a single command.

### Does expandtab make softtabstop redundant?

`tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 shiftwidth=4 expandtab`

In insert mode, pressing the tab key inserts 4 spaces. Pressing the delete key deletes a single space - so you have to backspace 4 times if you hit the tab key by accident.

`tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab`

In insert mode, pressing the tab key inserts 4 spaces. Pressing the backspace key deletes 4 spaces.

If I am working with `expandtab` switched on, I would prefer the delete key to remove the same amount of whitespace as the tab key inserts. So in this case, too, I feel that it would be useful to be able to assign the same value to `tabstop`, `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` simultaneously.

### A shortcut would still be useful

It's great that Vim provides so much flexibility, but I can't see myself needing it. I just want to be able to choose the width of a tab, and whether it is a 'hard' tab (using a tab character) or a 'soft' tab (made up of spaces). Toggling between hard and soft tabs is easy enough (`:set expandtab!`), but I wish it was more straightforward to set the width of tab, without having to fiddle with 3 different parameters.

So my proposed suggestion for something like `:set stab=4` still sounds good to me.

Comment: It appears as though you have two different questions here, perhaps you should split your question into two.

Comment: You're right! I've moved the second question into a topic of its own.

Comment: This seems like an RFE rather than a question. As such, you should probably propose to the VIM community: http://www.vim.org/community.php -- or simply write a patch. Other than that, VIM has an extensive macro facility that allows you to define new operations, so it's very likely that you could simply create a macro that does what you want.

Comment: @nelstrom In regard to your question `is there a practical case where you wouldn't want shiftwidth == tabstop && tabstop == softtabstop?`, Vim's own source code uses `set shiftwidth=4  tabstop=8 noexpandtab`.  Yes, one typically wants `shiftwidth == softtabstop`, but that's independent of what value `tabstop` has.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Creating a `stab` option in Vim itself would not be easy, but I've whipped up this command/function that you can drop in your `.vimrc` (or a plugin file if you're super-organized). Use `:Stab` and you will be prompted for an indent level and whether or not to use `expandtab`. If you hit enter without giving it a new indent level, it will just print the current settings.

```
" put all this in your .vimrc or a plugin file
command! -nargs=* Stab call Stab()
function! Stab()
  let l:tabstop = 1 * input('set shiftwidth=')

  if l:tabstop > 0
    " do we want expandtab as well?
    let l:expandtab = confirm('set expandtab?', "&Yes\n&No\n&Cancel")
    if l:expandtab == 3
      " abort?
      return
    endif

    let &l:sts = l:tabstop
    let &l:ts = l:tabstop
    let &l:sw = l:tabstop

    if l:expandtab == 1
      setlocal expandtab
    else
      setlocal noexpandtab
    endif
  endif

  " show the selected options
  try
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon 'set tabstop='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:ts
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon ' shiftwidth='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:sw
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon ' sts='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:sts . ' ' . (&l:et ? '  ' : 'no')
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon 'expandtab'
  finally
    echohl None
  endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! It does more than I asked for - I think I'd prefer to keep expandtab out of it - but I can easily customise it to my liking. You've provided me with a small crash course in Vimscript, so I'm very grateful. The 100 point bounty is yours!

Answer (score 9):

This is my first attempt at writing VimScript, but here goes:

```
function! Stab(value)
    let &shiftwidth  = a:value
    let &softtabstop = a:value
    let &tabstop     = a:value
endfunc
```

If I put this in my .vimrc file, I can call it by running `:call Stab(X)`, where X is the desired tab width. This is an adequate solution for now, but if anyone can suggest a way of making it easier to call I would be grateful.

I've also created a function that quickly summarizes the current settings, which I have mapped to ctrl-Tab:

```
nmap <C-Tab> :call TabParams()<CR>
function! TabParams()
    echo "tabstop:     ".&tabstop
    echo "shiftwidth:  ".&shiftwidth
    echo "softtabstop: ".&softtabstop
endfunc
```

*Well, I put up a 100 point bounty for this answer, and now I've half solved it myself. Not sure if I can accept my own answer...*

Comment: +1 yeah, but if this is what you really want, it's still an ok answer.

Comment: You'll probably want to use let &l:shiftwidth, etc to set the local versions.

Answer (score 7):

You can in edit mode also use <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> to indent and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to deindent to the next indentation level as set by `shiftwidth`, regardless of the `tabstop`, `softtabstop` or `expandtab` settings. Vim will automatically add/remove spaces or tabs to bring you to the right column.

If you use these commands to control indentation instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Backspace</kbd> you don't have to worry about all these tab settings fitting together and always get to the correct indentation level.

Answer (score 3):

If `expandtab` is set then (as too much php points out), `softtabstop` becomes redundant. The only reason you might set `shiftwidth` differently from `tabstop` would be to cater to an odd habit; for instance, you use four-space indents but you prefer <kbd>tab</kbd> to insert eight spaces.

If `expandtab` is unset then things get fuzzier. If you want your code to look the same in with `cat` and non-vim editors as it does in vim, then `tabstop` should always be set at 8; in this case you would set `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` both to your preferred indent level. If you instead prefer that every "physical tab" in the file represents one indent level, you would set `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` to your preferred indent level and leave `softtabstop` at zero (setting it equal to `tabstop` is equivalent except that if you change `tabstop` it will get out of sync, while zero just means "ignore this please").

Comment: I think this is wrong because only with `softtabstop` set to the right value, will backspace delete a spaced indent as if it was a tab. which is a must for sane use.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `softtabstop` and `expandtab` is wrong - so the `stab` option you suggest wouldn't be very useful.

**`expandtab`** is for when you want to use spaces instead of tabs for *everything*. If you set `expandtab`, then Vim ignores the `softtabstop` option and uses `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` to work out how many spaces to insert.

**`softtabstop`** is only for when you would like to use a **mix** of tabs and spaces, allowing you to indent with fine control (2 or 4 spaces), while keeping tab width at a higher value (usually 8) so that text appears in the other applications. Setting `softtabstop=tabstop` doesn't accomplish anything because Vim will always use tabs for indenting.

**Update:** As [kaizer.se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137317/kaizer-se) has pointed out, if you are using `expandtab`, then you still need to set `softtabstop` if you want Vim to backspace multiple spaces as though they are a tab.

Comment: While you're right that `tabstop` and `softtabstop` become one variable too many when `extpandtab` is set, I think you're wrong on the priority. Just try it: set `ts=8 sts=4 et` and press tab; the cursor will be in column five, and four spaces will be inserted, just as if you had set `ts=4 sts=0 et`.

Comment: I think this is wrong because only with `softtabstop` set to the right value, will backspace delete a spaced indent as if it was a tab. which is a must for sane use.

Answer (score 2):

Are you changing your white space settings so often you really need a function to manage that?  If you are messing with tabstop a lot and also setting expandtab, you are probably going to have a mess over time as you change files with different values passed to `stab`.  Today I use `:call stab (4)`, tomorrow it's `:call stab (2)` and last week it was `:call stab (8)`.  Sounds like even if you write it, you'll soon stop using it.

If you plan to always pass the same value to stab, why not just edit your global settings?  In vim:

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

and add the following:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4  "tabs are 4 spaces wide (default = 8)
set expandtab     "Convert tabs to spaces
```

This is how my .vimrc is setup.

Answer (score 1):

One useful option is `softtabstop=-1` which will set it to the value of `shiftwidth`. 
You can also set `shiftwidth` to 0, in which case the `tabstop` value will be used.