# How do I use variables in my .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I have a small problem with "tab size" and different project, 
some like 2 or 4 and the Linux kernel like 8 spaces per tab.

And this is not a big problem since I can just change a couple of settings in my .vimrc

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

But that is 3 lines I need to change...

It would be nice to have one line with a variable with the number 2,4 or 8.

A little bit like

```
let l:tabsize=4
set tabstop=l:tabsize
set shiftwidth=l:tabsize
set softtabstop=l:tabsize
```

But this don't work...

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks
Johan

---

*Update*: 
This solves my little problem.

```
let tabsize = 4
execute "set tabstop=".tabsize
execute "set shiftwidth=".tabsize
execute "set softtabstop=".tabsize
```

Comment: See also the answers at [Tab Vs Space preferences in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1562336).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can't use variables on the rhs in the .vimrc.

try :help feature-list for more info.  for unix vs windows for example (not sure what your projects are):

```
if has("unix")
    " do stuff for Unix
elseif has("win32")
    " do stuff for Windows
endif
```

might work, or another example is

```
execute "set path=".g:desktop_path
```

If g:desktop_path contains spaces, you will have to escape those, either
in the original setting of g:desktop_path or when setting 'path', e.g.,

```
execute "set path=".escape(g:desktop_path, ' ')
```

See

```
:help let-option
:help execute
:help escape()
```

Comment: Accepted Solution since you provided a "execute" syntax example... it was the missing part.

Comment: Also, the `let &path = g:desktop_path` doesn't work; only the `execute` approach

Comment: I've removed the non-working example (note to those who voted for an edit, your edit contained a typo hence the reject).

Answer (score 15):

This is working:

```
let my_sw = 20
let &sw = my_sw
```

Now you can figure how to fix your code

Comment: For those that are curious about this syntax, you can visit [this page](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html).  For short, `my_sw` is a variable declared by us, and we can prefiex a `&` to built-in options to uses them as variables, like `&sw` here.

Answer (score 13):

As this topic was brought to life again here are my few bits:

```
" In the vimrc
set softtabstop=-1 " Make 'softtabstop' follow 'shiftwidth'
set shiftwidth=0   " Make 'shiftwidth' follow 'tabstop'

" Somewhere else
let &tabstop=l:tabsize " Assign 'tabstop' a value of local tabsize variable
" or, typed manually
set ts=4
```

. And please forget about `execute 'set option='.var`. `let &option=var` is available since at least `vim-7.0`.

Answer (score 5):

This solution doesn't use local variables, but it will get you the result you want using just your `.vimrc` file. Just add the code below to your `.vimrc` file and add more project-specific options (even mappings) to the corresponding functions below. (Remember to change the globbing paths in the `autocmd!` lines to the appropriate folder name.)

```
autocmd! BufReadPost,BufNewFile */myProject/** call <SID>MyProjectOptions()
autocmd! BufReadPost,BufNewFile */linux-kernel/** call <SID>LinuxKernelOptions()

function! <SID>MyProjectOptions()
    " everything in this function only applies to myProject files
    setlocal tabstop=4
    ...
endfunction

function! <SID>LinuxKernelOptions()
    " everything in this function only applies to linux kernel files
    setlocal tabstop=8
    ...
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that toggles colorcolumn on/off when you hit leader+c:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :execute "set colorcolumn=" . (&cc == "+1" ? "0" : "+1")<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been troubled by this problem for a **very** long time, too. This is especially painful when I need to work with other people's code concurrently, which forces me to change the indent size back and forth frequently. I used to have something similar to OP's solution, but that still requires updating the `.vimrc` file every time. Later, I learned I can just define this function that I could call from the editor:

```
function! SetTabSize(size)
    execute "set tabstop=".a:size
    execute "set shiftwidth=".a:size
    execute "set softtabstop=".a:size
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Sts call SetTabSize(<f-args>)
```

In the editor, if you want to change the current indent size to 4, just do:

```
:Sts 4
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You don’t need a function any longer: recent vim version support special values of `shiftwidth` and `softtabstop` that make them follow `tabstop` value (`softtabstop` will follow `shiftwidth` which will follow `tabstop`, not something more simple as both following `tabstop`). See my answer.