# Spaces as tabs and backspace behavior in Vim

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

set to use 4 spaces instead of tab when I hit the Tab button. But when I hit backspace after a Tab, I need to backspace all 4 spaces. Is there a way to have it so when I go to backspace a "tab" it can delete all 4 spaces?

Comment: Incidental note: you can have multiple `set` options on one line, so you can have `set sw=4 ts=4 et sts=4`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try `set softtabstop=4`

Comment: To me, this is one of the hardest basic options to understand from its description in the vim documentation. Can't blame anyone for missing it. "It 'feels' like <Tabs>s are being inserted, while in fact a mix of spaces and <Tab>s is used." Say what? Magic?

Comment: I got [really confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562336/tab-vs-space-preferences-in-vim/1610732#1610732) about these settings, so I made a screencast about [tabs and spaces in Vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/). I hope it helps to clarify things.

Answer (score 10):

You can try using ^T and ^D.

```
:help i_CTRL-T
:help i_CTRL-D
```

These allow to insert or delete (more like backspace though) a number of spaces equal to shiftwidth.

Comment: Nice one!  Mapping this as follows gives a natural feel for me: `inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you earlier, but I soon find it do not make any sense to just backspace 1 character in real coding.
but if you really want backspace 1 character, you can just type one more space, then you can delete only one character each time you hit space bar even if you got where there you typed the 4 spaces tab