# vi have backspace undo previous autoindent

Tags: vi, auto-indent

I currently have `vi` set to autoindent when I start a new line, but if I want to remove the autoindent I have to do something like hit backspace four times.  Is there a way to have the backspace key remove indentation after an autoindent instead of deleting only one space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151448/spaces-as-tabs-and-backspace-behavior-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> removes the autoindent by an indention level. Starting a new line puts you in insert mode, and the mentioned keys are a standard insert mode key binding to undo an automatic indention level.
This allows you to remove whole indention levels (using the mentioned keys) without sacrificing the possibility to remove only a single space using the backspace key.