# How to make vim traverse 4 spaces as if they were tabs?

Tags: vim

The thing that bothers me about the (nearly) ubiquitous decision to move spaces is that in something like vim it still treats 4 spaces as 4 spaces for the sake of traversing cursor position with arrow keys.

I've [figured out how to delete 4 spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151448/spaces-as-tabs-and-backspace-behavior-in-vim) at a time... But how can vim be configured to traverse 4 consecutive spaces at a time as if it were really a tab?

Comment: this is the wrong question to ask. the good question would be to ask yourself where you want to move to? the next word maybe? try `w` instead of `hjkl`

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `^`? It will place the cursor on the first non-blank character of the line. Anyway, `:help navigation` should answer all your questions.

Comment: For jumping 4 spaces forward, it's easy to do stuff like `4l`, and maybe record it as a macro (`:help q`) so you can do it with `@@`, or bind it to the keypress sequence of your choosing (`:help map`); so I think you must be asking for something different. Are you looking to make the <tab> key function like it does on a typewriter (jumping forward a specific distance, regardless of the cursor current location)? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @m_mlvx what you suggest is easy only if you know about macros and mappings. OP may not have that knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the question explicitly mentions arrow keys while more seasoned Vim users would usually use `hjkl` for navigation. These have the minor advantage that they can be used without leaving the home row.

Don't get me wrong, there's nothing inherently wrong with using the arrow keys. It's just that Vim offers more powerful alternatives.

Even when going with `l`, the cursor moves only one character at the time.

Traversing a file character by character reminds me of driving with someone shouting bad directions from the passenger's seat. Like "left, straight, right, right, straight, stop" instead of "go around that block, then turn into the parking lot". You will eventually get there, it's just not efficient and a little bit unnerving.

In the comments, a lot of sensible ideas have been proposed and I throw in some more:

- `w` jumps to the start of the next word.
- `^` jumps to the first non-blank character.
- `[count]l` (e.g. `4l`) moves `[count]` characters to the right.
- `[count]|` jump to `[count]`th column.
- `f<char>` jump to the next occurrence of `<char>` on the line.

In Vim, type [`:help left-right-motions`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#left-right-motions) to see a lot of commands for horizontal movement. There's a learning curve to it and I can see how a lot of commands to do something seemingly simple can be intimidating.

There exist also other text editors besides Vim, even on relatively bare Linux systems. Different editors offer different features such as a heuristic to go by virtual tabs. If it's a must-have, I'd consider trying out other editors as well.

Now that all the sensible ideas have been discussed, let's talk about bad ideas. For no other reason than to kill some time, I came up with the following Vim script which - I think - nobody should have in their `vimrc`s:

```
function! JumpToNextTab()
    let c = col('.')
    let sw = shiftwidth(c)
    let ns = (c/sw + 1) * sw
    if match(getline('.'), '^ \{'.(c-ns).'}', c-1) > -1
        return ns.'|'
    endif
    return 'l'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <right> JumpToNextTab()
xnoremap <expr> <right> JumpToNextTab()
inoremap <expr> <right> '^O'.JumpToNextTab()
```

Now this abomination of a function will move normally when on text but when on white space, it will look ahead if there's nothing but spaces until the next multiple of `shiftwidth` and if so, jump there. This only works for moving right and will break horribly when the `vartabstop` option is set and probably on several more occasions.

This also offers mappings for normal, visual and insert modes. The mapping for insert mode needs to be prefixed with <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> (see [`:help i_CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O)) to execute the command. You can create the `^O` thing by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>.

Now that you've seen it, pressing `w` does not seem so bad after all, does it?

Comment: Thanks for all the extra context in the answer.