# vi plugin - Stab - replace regular tabs with spaces, bundle as plugin and autostart

Tags: vim, plugins, vi, indentation

for long period I'm looking for a good indentation plugin, and recently I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610732/2034967 
this is an awesome indentation(the best in my personal opinion) and I use it permanently - part of my `.vimrc` file and every time I start vi I turn it on, and if not, then I use :retab to fix the `\t` tabs after turning on `:Stab`.

My actual question is how to turn it into a separate bundle bundle and to configure it to auto start with the wanted(to use 4 spaces instead of tab) parameters configurations automatically and only disabling(turning off and going back to default tabs) the plugin on demand using `:Stab`?

Background about my working environment: vim running on linux (mostly MCP linux distro) in command line (not GUI vim)

I'm asking it because I tried to follow the vim guides to create a plugin and failed..
I event tried some vim plugins for managing plugins like 
https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen
and without success.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What vim guide did you follow? How did it fail?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_write_a_plugin for the vim plugin
and I tried to set up vim-pathogen and define Stab as a bundle. How did it fail? I created a the plugin file from the Stab source lined above in `~.vim/Stab` but couldn't activate it from the vim command line using `:Stab` , same result from the pathogen created a the file under: `~/.vim/bundle` and inserted the pathogen execution into my .vimrc but still couldn't activate `:Stab`

Answer (score 0):

Without Pathogen, your single-file script should be placed here:

```
~/.vim/plugin/stab.vim
```

With Pathogen or Vundle, you should install it like this:

```
~/.vim/bundle/stab/plugin/stab.vim
```

Because of how Vim loads plugins, the `Stab` command won't be available when your `~/.vimrc` is executed, however, because of its interactive nature, I'm not sure it is a good idea to execute the `Stab` command every time you start Vim.

It is possible, though, to modify it so that it can be run non-interactively, using global variables, for example, or autoloading… But at that point, it would work *exactly* like having the relevant options in your `~/.vimrc` which doesn't sound that practical to me. And relatively wasteful.

Anyway, the following (quick) version makes it possible to run the script non-interactively from your `~/.vimrc`. You can still use `:Stab` if you want to execute it interactively.

For this to work, you must install the script here:

```
~/.vim/autoload/stab.vim
```

and add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
call stab#stab(4, 1)
```

The first argument is your desired `shiftwidth` and the second argument is a boolean: `0` if you don"t want `expandtab`, `1` if you want `expandtab`. Make sure this line comes *after* any indentation settings.

Modified script:

```
if exists("g:loaded_stab") || &cp
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_stab = 1

command! -nargs=* Stab call stab#stab(<f-args>)

function! stab#stab(...)

  if a:0 > 0
    let l:tabstop = 1 * a:1
  else
    let l:tabstop = 1 * input('set shiftwidth=')
  endif

  if l:tabstop > 0
    " do we want expandtab as well?
    if a:0 > 1
      let l:expandtab = a:2
    else
      let l:expandtab = confirm('set expandtab?', "&Yes\n&No\n&Cancel")
    endif
    if l:expandtab == 3
      " abort?
      return
    endif

    let &l:sts = l:tabstop
    let &l:ts = l:tabstop
    let &l:sw = l:tabstop

    if l:expandtab == 1
      setlocal expandtab
    else
      setlocal noexpandtab
    endif
  endif

  " show the selected options
  try
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon 'set tabstop='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:ts
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon ' shiftwidth='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:sw
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon ' sts='
    echohl Question
    echon &l:sts . ' ' . (&l:et ? '  ' : 'no')
    echohl ModeMsg
    echon 'expandtab'
  finally
    echohl None
  endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, when vim loads it loads stab,
I have two additional questions following your explanation:

1) 
2)

Comment: Full comment:
Thanks, this works, when vim loads it loads stab,
I have two additional questions following your explanation:

1) when vi loads it prompts to press "enter" to validate the given values, is there an way to configure the function in a way that it will not wait for the "enter" configraion?
2) is it possible to configure this script so it will be possible toggle back to default settings - that tabs are regular tabs and not  spaces spaces?

thanks for the help mate!

Comment: I would answer "yes" to both questions but I don't have much time to dig further ATM. Maybe tonight!